# Как обновить div при клике?

Tags: javascript

Как можно обновить div при клике на кнопку через javascript?

```
<a href="#" id="update">Обновить</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что обновить?
Как-то условий маловато.

Так?

```js
function update(){
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = 'Обновлено?';
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('#update').addEventListener('click', update);
});
```

[Посмотреть пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lo96wau/)

Comment: @KYRAN, Возраст тут ни при чём. Но пожалуйста.